# Excel VBA range naming

Tags: excel, vba

Replace cell reference with named range

MY range is already named "Sequences" and consists of cells PB1 through AFS1.
The VBA code already exists and runs.
THe VBA code performs a simple test on the cell in row 1 of each column.
The code now reads,

```
Dim c as range
. . . 
 For Each c In Range("PB1:AFS1").Cells
. . .
```

Please tell me how to follow best practice:
In the "For each" statement, use code that uses "Sequences" to refer to the first and last columns of the range "Sequences". No explicit cell references.

Yes, my question is, indeed, very simple.
But I don't know VBA syntax.

Thanks!

I expect to avoid re-entering explicity cell reference whenever added columns change the size or location of "Sequences"

Comment: Sorry, the range actually consists of cells PB1 through AFS307.

Answer (score 0):

No need to refer to the first and last columns.

To refer to the first row of that range, for example:

```
 Range("Sequences").Rows(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer them directly using. So if your Range is `PB1:AFS307`

- **First Column** -  `Range("Sequences").Columns(1)` will give `PB1:PB307`
- **Last Column** - `Range("Sequences").Columns(Range("Sequences").Columns.Count)` will give `AFS1:AFS307`

To access the 1st cell you can do this

`Range("Sequences").Columns(1).Rows(1)` will give `PB1`